# What git tag names and description should I give when implementing a feature on a big application repo?

Tags: git, tags, annotate

Take the example of **branches** and **commit messages** related to my question:

- When I work on a *feature*, I name my branch **feat/featureName**
- When I want to *test* something, I checkout my **junk/nameOfTest** branch
- When I commit, I apply [7 rules of a great commit message](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#seven-rules)

All these being said, is there a pattern I could follow to write good **git tag** *names* and *descriptions* in a huge repo where everyone works on his own feature?

E.g. if I work on a "user groups" feature, after 10 commits where I created the basic CRUD, should I **tag** it with **v0.1-alpha-groups** and in **description** I should list all controls available by now?

Please give me some examples of good **git tag** *naming* and *description* best-practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using **[semver2 (Semantic Versioning)](http://semver.org/)** for the tag naming convention.

After that, you can check out "[Command-line tips for effective release announcements](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/command-line-tips-for-effective-release-announcements/)", which have some good tips, including the release notes production:

> If your release isn't large, your release notes could include a summary of the contained commits; this is useful for minor point releases. You can use `git shortlog` to do this:

```
$ git shortlog 0.5..0.6 --no-merges
David Winterbottom (661):
      Add defaults to the counts on the product summary dashboard page
      Tidy up urls.py and settings.py
      Use mirrors when pip installing the demo site
      Install django-oscar-stores
      Add link to stores page in footer
...
```

> You can even use --format to provide links to Github commits:

```
$ git shortlog 0.3.4..0.4 --no-merges --format="%s (https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-stores/commit/%h)"
```

> This won't always be appropriate if your release if there are thousands of commits.

You have a similar approach in "[Very Easy Changelogs with Git](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1649/very-easy-changelogs-with-git)":

```
git log 1.0.0...1.1.0 --pretty=format:'<li> %s &mdash; %cn &bull; <a href="http://github.com/<username>/<repo>commit/%H" target="_blank">%h</a></li>' | grep -v Merge > changelog.html
```